# React Typescript property does not exist on type / IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

New to TypeScript and this feels like it should be really simple but I can't quite get the syntax happy!

Very simple component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import ControlArea from "./ControlArea";

interface IControlAreaProps {
  welcome?: any;
}

export class Layout extends React.Component<IControlAreaProps> {
  public render() {
    return (
        <ControlArea welcome="This is the control area"/>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting the TS error `Property 'welcome' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ControlArea> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>...'.`

Any point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake here is that you're adding the interface to the Layout component when you should be adding them to the ControlArea component

```
interface IControlAreaProps {
  welcome?: any
}

export default class ControlArea extends React.Component<IControlAreaProps> {
  // Your ControlArea code
}
```

Comment: Of course! Makes no sense to apply to the layout! Thank you :)